# Passing of a variable (an ID) to another compiled UI in pyqt

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt, qt-designer

I've been stumped for more than an hour on how to pass a variable, specifically an ID in sqlite which was recently accessed, to be used to another UI generated. I'm using eric4 (with python, pyqt, qtdesigner and sqlite).

Basically the program I'm coding makes members and each member has a unique ID when the information of the member is generated. When there is a new member made, the ID assigned to the new member must be passed to another part of the program. But there are also instances where there must be modifications made in the member, the ID must be known to display the right information of the member.

Basically, when a new member is added, it first inputs the the information in the database. What I did is like this in the dialog code of that ui named newmember.py:

```
def on_button_Save_released(self):
    Nik = unicode(self.LineEdit_Nickname.text())
    self.NMem = NewMem()
    self.NMem.input_data(Nik)
    self.close()
```

The `NewMem` is a class in another py file which has access to the database. Parts of the input_data method goes like this:

```
    cur.execute("insert into Members (Nick) values (?)",(Nik))
```

I added this code so that it will know what ID the new member is assigned::

```
    CurrentID = cur.lastrowid
    return CurrentID
```

So I changed this line `self.NMem.input_data(Nik)` in the ui dialog code newmember.py into this

```
    ID = self.NMem.input_data(Nik)
```

so that the ID will be passed.

Now, the dialog code will open another window and I want the returned ID be used to another ui. Basically the whole method in ui dialog code in newmember.py is like this so far:

```
def on_button_Save_released(self):
    Nik = unicode(self.LineEdit_Nickname.text())
    self.NMem = NewMem()
    ID = self.NMem.input_data(Nik)
    self.close()

    self.Pts = Points()
    self.Pts.show()
```

The `Points()` is a class in another ui dialog code which will show in the `Points` ui the information of the member. But the returned `ID` information must be passed to the `Points()` ui so that the right information be displayed. I have a hunch that I would be needing to change some parts in the compiled ui form so that it knows the `ID` to be displayed but how will I pass it in there compiled ui form?

Any help is very much appreciated *bows deeply*

**Edit:** Is there a way in this code -

```
    self.Pts = Points()
    self.Pts.show()
```

be the variable ID be also incorporated and will pass into the ui? Like

```
    self.Pts = Points
    self.Pts.show(ID)
```

that the ID will be going to the ui also?

**Edit2:** Is there a way how to pass variables in classes of a ui in python just like how it was shown here - http://www.daniweb.com/forums/thread64758.html

Comment: Not sure if I get the whole concept but maybe you want to look into if promoting your class in Designer gets you anywhere. 
It's a bit funky to make it work with PyQt but I found it to be pretty useful.

Comment: Hmm... now that I reread my post, it's a bit of a tl;dr - well, basically, I want a value from a value (ID) will be dependent on the display of a ui. I'm stumped on how to have the value to be passed to the ui ._. Edit: is there a way where the self.Pts.show() will also input a variable? I have no idea why you see (also editing the main question)

Comment: Can you add your implementation of the Points class to the question?

Answer (score 0):

I believe using a Qt model with a QDataWidgetMapper is the Qt way of solving this problem. [An example here](https://github.com/Werkov/PyQt4/blob/master/examples/itemviews/simplewidgetmapper.py). (QSLTableModel or subclass QAbstractTableModel if you want to program the database communication yourself).

You can also check SQL Widget mapper example in the Qt docs.

Personally I prefer to use a custom model because I've previously stumbled upon deployment problems using Qt's SQL, but your mileage may vary.